# Angular 10 Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular10

So, after i upgraded my Angular Application to Angular 10 (from 7) i get the Following Error when serving the Application via `ng serve`.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/lizenz-list/lizenz-list.component.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

The HTML file looks like this

```
<ng-template #CRUDTemplatePluginTableCaption>
   <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
      <button type="button" style="margin-right: 10px" pButton icon="ui-icon-add" 
      (click)="addCRUDItem()"></button>
      <button type="button" pButton icon="far fa-server" (click)="getServerInfo()"></button>
   </div>
 </ng-template>
```

The template of lizenz-list.ts looks like this: 
`` template: `${CRUDBasicListComponent_Template || ''}${LizenzListComponent_Template}` `` 
Perhaps this could be the issue?

On Angular 7 everything worked fine, i just cant find the answer to the Problem.

EDIT: I am Using [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) as an UI Library. 
CRUDBasicListComponent_Template is an Exported html Template that looks like this:

```
    <p-table [properties etc..]>
      <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <!--Where the ng-Template from Lizenz should be replaced -->
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="CRUDTemplatePluginTableCaption"> 
        </ng-container>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <!--HEADER-->
       </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-CRUDItem let-columns="columns">
        <!--BODY WITH DATA-->
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

Comment: What is e.g. CRUDBasicListComponent_Template? Is this an exported constant of a typescript file that contains the template string? Or is it a public component field?

Comment: Oh yea sorry, ill edit the Question